# C++ recent cast error

Tags: c++, casting

While maintaining old code that uses libmxl2 I get the following error:

```
error: invalid static_cast 
       from type ‘const char [8]’ 
       to type ‘xmlChar* {aka unsigned char*}’
```

in the following piece of code:

```
xmlNodePtr messageNode = doc->children; // The "Message" node
if(xmlStrcmp(messageNode->name, static_cast<xmlChar*>("Message"))) ... blabla
```

(same error happens with `reinterpret_cast`)

Obviously I can resolve with an old style cast `(xmlChar*)` but what is the proper way of doing this recently in C++?

I use gcc 4.7.2 (and this code was last time compiled 5 years ago :) without this error, but do not ask the version of the old compiler :) )

Comment: Is "Message" always a string literal?

Comment: You need a const_cast probably, or better yet, get a newer version of the xml API which hopefully has better const correctness.

Comment: @wich: The interface takes an `xmlChar*` (which is a typedef for unsigned char). `const_cast` would be to remove `const`.

Comment: @staticx yes, exactly it removes const from the literal so that it matches the non_const input argument

Comment: @wich: Right, sorry misunderstood what you were saying.

Comment: @const_casters: invalid const_cast from type ‘const char*’ to type ‘xmlChar* {aka unsigned char*}’

Comment: so presumably static_cast<const xmlChar *>("Message") would also work?

Comment: @GrahamGriffiths nope :(  invalid static_cast from type ‘const char [8]’ to type ‘const xmlChar* {aka const unsigned char*}’

Comment: @fritzone you also need a static cast since you're going from signed chars to unsigned chars

Comment: I guess doing something like this won't work for you: `unsigned char arr[] = "Message" ;` and then use `arr`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after some combination of casts this works:

```
const_cast<xmlChar*>(reinterpret_cast<const xmlChar *>("Message"))
```

Comment: Casting away the `const` can be problematic, you have to be sure that the function will never try and modify that argument otherwise you have undefined behavior.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour This goes into the libxml I really hope it will not modify it :)

Comment: You are probably ok but if it can be avoided it should.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: The conversion from char* to unsigned char* is safe because all objects can be treated as an array of char, unsigned char, or signed char in C++.

Comment: @staticx I was commenting on casting away constness, not sure how that applies.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: Casting from `const char*` to `char*` is safe.

Comment: @staticx not so if some crazy bit of code will want to modify it later :( The compiler might place this text in a special memory area reserved for const data ... Anyway, I will think about the design of this later, right now I just wanted to compile it!

Answer (score 1):

Get a newer version of libxml2. The [current version of the API](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-xmlstring.html) has the following signature:

```
int xmlStrcmp  (const xmlChar * str1, 
                const xmlChar * str2)
```

Which is compatible with your const string literal.

As you're stuck with an older version of libxml2 you'll have to `const_cast` away the constness of the literal and depend on the library not trying to modify the string that you pass it. You'll also need a `reinterpret_cast` as "regular" chars are usually signed instead of unsigned, e.g.

```
xmlStrcmp(messageNode->name, reinterpret_cast<xmlChar*>(const_cast<char*>("Message")))
```

By the way, the reason that you need a `reinterpret_cast` instead of a plain old `static_cast` is because you are casting a pointer type to a pointer type pointing at a differently typed object.

Comment: @staticx, yes const_cast will get rid of the error, but in general it's really bad form to use const_cast, especially when doing so on inputs of third party API, as the third party could change the code to something that **does** actually change the string and then you'd have a crash.

Comment: Eh, good point. But you can only rely on the API you have at the time.

Comment: This version comes by default with my ubuntu (12.10), and we're sort of stuck to it ...

Answer (score 0):

As has been stated here a couple of times, you can get the newest version of the lib which is [const correct](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Const-correctness)

If that is not an option for any reason, then what you need is a `const_cast` instead of a `static_cast`

Your code should look like

```
if(xmlStrcmp(messageNode->name, 
  const_cast<xmlChar*>(reinterpret_cast<const xmlChar *>("Message"))))
```

You can tell this is the case, by looking at the error message

> error: invalid static_cast 
>          from type ‘const char [8]’ 
>          to type ‘xmlChar* {aka unsigned char*}’

the only difference between the two incompatible types is the const modifier

Answer (score 0):

`xmlChar` after some research is `typedef` to `unsigned char`. Therefore,

A solution is :

```
    // use the implicit conversion to 'char*' to cast away constness:
    char* message = "Message";

    // explicitly cast to 'unsigned char*'
    unsigned char* in = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(message);
    xmlChar* test = in;
```

The removal of constness is usually a bad idea since string literals are not modifiable, but sometimes it is necessary when dealing with legacy libraries that are not const-correct.

The conversion from `char*` to `unsigned char*` is safe because all objects can be treated as an array of `char`, `unsigned char`, or `signed char` in C++.